# C++ Remove all non-number charachters from std::string

Tags: c++, regex, string

What is an efficient way to remove all chars within in a string which are not in the range from 0 to 9?

```
string s = "h3ll0";
string numbers = removeNonNumbersFromString(s);
cout << numbers << endl;
```

output should be `30`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your own attempt and show it to us, describing what problems you have with it.

Comment: You can't really get better then the erase-remove idiom if you want to do it in-place.  Look that up and apply what you learn.

Comment: C++ have many nice [algorithm functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), including [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) which might be to your liking (together with a suitable [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) and [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)).

Comment: Never heard about erase-remove idiom, what is it? Please refer to an example or link!

Comment: If you search for it, you'll find many articles/posts explaining what erase-remove idiom is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example how to achieve it using `std::isdigit` and erase-remove idiom (which were mentioned in comments to your question):

```
std::string s = "h3ll0";

s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](unsigned char c)
{
    return !std::isdigit(c);
}), s.end());

std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you helped me and solved my problem!